# How to make iCloud container sync between devices

Tags: swift, swiftui, cloudkit

I am trying to use iCloud on xcode but I am not able to sync my iphone data to my apple watch.

I have created a a content view with

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \MyItem.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<MyItem>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }
```

with the following app

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct testingIcloudApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

I have then Create a similar target for the apple watch with the content view being

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \MyItem.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<MyItem>
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("hello")
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
...
```

with the app view being

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct testingAPicloud_Watch_AppApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

My persistance contoler look like

```
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        
        let newAlarm = Alarm(context: viewContext)
        newAlarm.on = false
        newAlarm.name = "Demo Alarm"
        newAlarm.hour = 12
        newAlarm.minute = 59
        newAlarm.hm = 12+59
        newAlarm.sound = "Radar"
        newAlarm.gentleWake = true
        
        let newSleep = NewSleep(context: viewContext)
        newSleep.beginDate = Date()
        newSleep.endDate = Date()
        
     
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "SMIOS")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    }
}
```

I have put icloud annd background modes for signing and capabilityis for both the IOS and the Apple watch.
[image: icloud enabled]
I have also set up the database with icloud kit enabled:
[image]

I can successfully run both apps but when adding an item on the iphone it isnt syncing with the Apple watch. There is only the text("hello").

I have also made sure that icloud is working on both physical devises

Comment: A watch app is an extension. You need an AppGroup. The url for the store should be in the AppGroup. The issue isn’t “between devices” it’s “between apps” a main app and an extension

Comment: @loremipsum watch apps haven't used app groups to share with iOS since watchOS 2, they now have their own local storage

Comment: @malhal are you going to share a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Apple watch is very slow to sync when using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`. Try putting it on charge to speed it up, especially for the first sync. For future syncs if you lock the iPhone, the watch is more likely to receive the silent push notification telling it to sync. You might need to use a background task to allow the watch app to run long enough to complete the sync.

Comment: I have been trying to sync them for hours. It is not a speed problem. It just looks like the IOS and apple watch have different storage and are not syncing.

Comment: make sure it is working between iphone device and iphone simulator first